# How can I obtain "Categories" from Wikipedia in the following way using rvest in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking to obtain Categories (Bottom most part of a Wikipedia page) using rvest in R. I have used SelectorGadget to identify the html nodes for categories extraction.  The code I am using is as follows

```
thepage <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Diego")
Categories <- thepage %>% 
            html_nodes("#mw-normal-catlinks") %>%
            html_text()
Categories
```

The result obtained is as follows:

```
"Categories: San Diego1769 establishments in California1850 establishments in CaliforniaCities in San Diego County, CaliforniaCounty seats in CaliforniaIncorporated cities and towns in CaliforniaPopulated coastal places in CaliforniaPopulated places established in 1769San Antonio-San Diego Mail LineSan Diego County, CaliforniaSan Diego metropolitan areaSpanish mission settlements in North AmericaSpecial economic zones of the United StatesStagecoach stops in the United States"
```

As you can observe, there are no delimiters to distinguish between categories. The first category is "San Diego" and the second category is "1769 establishments in California". How can I obtain these categories in a list or separated somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Each category is a list item, so you need to go into the list:

```
thepage %>% 
  html_nodes(".mw-normal-catlinks ul li") %>% 
  html_text()

 [1] "San Diego"                                    "1769 establishments in California"           
 [3] "1850 establishments in California"            "Cities in San Diego County, California"      
 [5] "County seats in California"                   "Incorporated cities and towns in California" 
 [7] "Populated coastal places in California"       "Populated places established in 1769"        
 [9] "San Antonio-San Diego Mail Line"              "San Diego County, California"                
[11] "San Diego metropolitan area"                  "Spanish mission settlements in North America"
[13] "Special economic zones of the United States"  "Stagecoach stops in the United States"
```